# DataGridView: Disable Cell Editing on Click or Keystroke, Enable Cell Editing only on Double Click

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am display some data in `DataGridiView`.

By default cell edit is enabled on keystroke or on click, I want to disable it.

I want the cell value to be edited only on double click.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This is not very intuitive, you should have a good reason to do it

Comment: You could do something by mouse OnClick event handler I guess...

Comment: Set your  EditMode to `EditProgrammatically` and `BeginEdit` on double click.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the [`EditMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your `DataGridView` to `EditProgrammatically`. This makes editing begins only when the [`BeginEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit(v=vs.110).aspx) method is called.

Then handle [`CellDoubleClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.celldoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event and call [`BeginEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
}
```